# How can commenting be added to news articles in an existing Sharepoint 2007 news site?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

A client is asking to incorporate commenting on their news articles. They're using the Sharepoint news site template for their news publishing, etc. They want a simple commenting system, much like what is available on most blog engines, only they want it at the bottom of each news article.

I just thought I would ask around about an out of the box solution before I go quoting a custom dev solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with this a while back and the solution we found was to use a discussion borad list (out of the box) and we created a custom web part that we added to the page layout for news.

We had to do som trickery to add support for anonymous comments, but on the whole it works good and wasen't to much code.

Answer (score 1):

The [Community Kit for SharePoint](http://www.codeplex.com/CKS) does the whole commenting thing for blogs.
you may have to cut out the commenting part of it to get it to work with your news section however.

The commenting section of the Enhanced Blog Edition of CKS does to approval of comments and spam checking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same request.  I didn't find an existing solution, so I did it by copying from the standard Blog site template, plus custom coding.

From the template: Copy the definition for the blog comments list.  Remove the lookup fields, and use a feature to create the list on all publishing sites.

Custom code: Add a feature receiver to the comments feature, and use it to add the lookup fields for page id and title, (using the pages list as destination).  This needs to be done in code because you can't configure the destination list for lookup fields in XML, (or at least I don't know how).

Write controls for querying the comments list and adding to it, and place on the page layout.

Simpler approach: Don't use the standard blog comments list, just create your own, where the page reference is just a number and not a lookup field.  Pro: Less work.  Con: You miss out on the views that come with the standard list.